# Where does Android Lollipop keep the mmssms.db file?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I need to delete the file so I can clear my messages, because a factory reset is not an option, and various softwares have not been able to clear the messages.

I am already in root terminal mode, I just need the updated file location, because /data/data/com.whatever from the previous version does not exist.

My ability to receive text messages is impaired until I can reset this file. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, the solution was to enable root mode and then try the third-party applications again. would have been nice to be able to move the file to prune it down, but really, at this point i just need to get on with it. lesson learned: android lollipop can't handle the 30k messages my iphone 4 can. -.-